# Getting a field value from a LINQ query without Iteration

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following query in controller and I want to store a column value in a variable but I am not being able to iterate it. Here is my code:

```
var srmas = (
            from SRMAs in db.SRMAs
            join SRMAStatus in db.SRMAStatus on SRMAs.Status equals SRMAStatus.Id
            join PurchaseOrders in db.PurchaseOrders on SRMAs.PONumber equals PurchaseOrders.PONumber
            join Suppliers in db.Suppliers on PurchaseOrders.SupplierID equals Suppliers.SupplierID
            join SRMADetails in db.SRMADetails on SRMAs.Id equals SRMADetails.SRMAId
                where(SRMAs.Id == srmaid)
                group SRMADetails by new 
                {
                    SRMADetails.Id, 
                    SRMADetails.SRMAId, 
                    SRMADetails.SupplierPartNum, 
                    SRMAs.PONumber, 
                    SRMAs.ActualAmount, 
                    SRMAs.ApprovedOn, 
                    SRMAs.Status, 
                    SRMAs.TrackingNumber,
                    SRMAs.SupplierRMANumber, 
                    SRMAs.RequestedFromSupp, 
                    SRMAs.CreatedOn, 
                    Suppliers.SupplierName, 
                    SRMAStatus.StatusName, 
                    PurchaseOrders.PODate, 
                    PurchaseOrders.suppliersOrderNumber 
                } into grp
                    select new 
                    {
                        grp.Key.Status,
                        grp.Key.SRMAId,
                        grp.Key.Id,
                        grp.Key.PONumber,
                        grp.Key.SupplierRMANumber,
                        grp.Key.ActualAmount,
                        grp.Key.SupplierPartNum,
                        grp.Key.RequestedFromSupp,
                        grp.Key.TrackingNumber,
                        grp.Key.ApprovedOn,
                        grp.Key.SupplierName,
                        grp.Key.StatusName,
                        grp.Key.PODate,
                        grp.Key.suppliersOrderNumber,
                        grp.Key.CreatedOn,
                        Sum = grp.Sum(SRMADetails => SRMADetails.Cost * SRMADetails.QtyReturned)
                    }
            ).ToList();

System.Collections.IEnumerable et = (System.Collections.IEnumerable)srmas;
IEnumerator it = et.GetEnumerator();
while (it.MoveNext())
{
    SRMA current = (SRMA)it.Current;
    Response.Write(current.Status);
}

ViewBag.SRMAs = srmas.Select(srma => new IndexViewModel
            {
                Id = srma.SRMAId,
                SupplierRMANum = srma.SupplierRMANumber,
                SRMADetailsID = srma.Id,
                PONumber = srma.PONumber,
                CreatedOn = srma.CreatedOn,
                SupplierName = srma.SupplierName,
                SRMAStatus = srma.StatusName,
                Status = srma.Status,
                suppliersOrderNumber = srma.suppliersOrderNumber,
                PODate = srma.PODate,
                Sum = srma.Sum,
                TrackingNumber = srma.TrackingNumber,
                ActualAmount = srma.ActualAmount
            }).ToList();
```

I just want to get `Status` value of first record. How do I do it?

Comment: why not use something like srmas.First().Status?

Comment: @Volatil3 Try :`srmas.FirstorDefault(lam=>lam.Status);`

Comment: Simplify your question first